# What is a procedural letter of promotion?

Tags: application, job, faculty-application, associate-professor

I recently saw several job postings for positions of associate professor and full professor at a university and each of these postings states the following in bold letters:

> **Candidates must provide a procedural letter of promotion to the rank of associate and full professor.**

What does this mean? What document does the candidate applying have to submit to fulfill this requirement for the application process?

Answer (score 2):

When I searched this exact phrasing on Google the posting I found also stated:

> In order to apply for a position of Associate / Full Professor, candidates must provide a letter of promotion from an academic institution with a documented due process to the rank of Associate / Full Professor.

This seems to be the same item requested, with a bit more detail explained later in the posting. I think this is pretty clear: you need to document that you've been promoted to that rank and document the process of that promotion, I don't know what else you'd need to add to this item to explain it further, but if you feel the need for further clarification it seems like you'd need to contact the university making the posting and ask them directly for that clarification.

It's pretty unusual to be hired directly to the ranks of Associate or Full professor without already holding an equivalent position. In some cases you may be able to effectively go through a tenure promotion process directly from a junior position when the hiring institution is either desperate or trying to woo a particular candidate for a job; it doesn't appear they are open to that sort of process for this job posting.

Comment: "It's pretty unusual to be hired directly to the ranks of Associate or Full professor without already holding an equivalent position." As far as Europe is concerned, pretty usual.